# jQuery and CSS Hover Effects Won't Work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't understand what is wrong, as similar code has worked for me before. I've created a div tag and styled it. But for some reason the hover feature in CSS doesn't affect it, and I tried adding jQuery code but the .mouseenter/.animate features don't work with it either. You can see the result of the code at [this link](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~rdekler/test).

The HTML code:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="This is intended as a page to test different designs and layouts.">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testStyle.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "test.js"></script>

    <title>
        Test 1
    </title>

</head>

<body>

        <div></div>

</body>
```

The CSS code:

```
html{
background-color : #000000 ;
}

div{
position : absolute ;
height : 50px ;
width : 50px ;

top : 50% ;
left : 50% ;

border : 1px solid #FFFF00;
border-radius : 50% ;

background-color : #FEFFBF ;
box-shadow : 0 0 40px #FEFFBF;
}

div:hover{
    background-color : '#0000FF' ;
}
```

The JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            background-color : '#0000FF' ;
    }) ;

    }) ;

    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            background-color : '#FEFFBF' ;           
        }) ;

    }) ;    
});
```

Comment: In javascript, you need to quote object keys if they contain special characters - `background-color` -> `"background-color"`

Comment: Start learning how to use the browser's console to debug errors.

Comment: Well the legit method should be this: `({backgroundColor:'#FEFFBF'});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (if you use the browser's console to help you troubleshoot you'll see this) has some syntax errors:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({
        'background-color' : '#0000FF' // ; remove the trailing semi-colon and quote the 'background-color'
        }) ;    
    }) ;

    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).animate({
        'background-color' : '#FEFFBF' // ; remove the trailing semi-colon and quote the 'background-color'          
        }) ;
    }) ;
});
```

Once the semi-colons are removed and your keys are quoted your code should not throw syntax errors.

Comment: Also a good note to state that any hyphenated property will become camel case and is better to use camel case since jquery uses another object to help the instance and by doing it camel case it's using javascript native property.  `backgroundColor`

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

#### CSS

```
div:hover{
    background-color : '#0000FF' ;
}
```

You placed quotes around the color string here, which is not valid CSS.  Remove the quotes, and the CSS hover will work correctly.

#### jQuery

```
$(this).animate({
    background-color : '#0000FF'
}) ;
```

You're passing an invalid object to jQuery.animate - javascript object keys must either be legal javascript identifiers, or be quotes strings.  The `-` character can't be used as part of an identifier, so you need to quote the keys.

```
$(this).animate({
    'background-color' : '#0000FF'
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as mentioned you had this wrong:

```
div:hover{
    background-color : '#0000FF' ;
}
```

Should be:

```
 div:hover{background-color : #0000FF;}
```

As far as **animate** Change your jquery to this (500 is just an example of the animation speed):

```
$('div').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#0000FF'}, 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#FEFFBF'}, 500);
});
```

Here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/af3nm/4/)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't do it in pure CSS3 ?

```
.div{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.75s 0.33s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.75s 0.33s;
    transition: all 0.75s 0.33s;
}

.div:hover{
  background-color:#blue; //for example
}
```

Comment: Just tried to bring a better solution to his question.